# True or False Questions about Open , Closed, and Closure Set.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

1. For any set A, complement of closure A is open => True since closure A is closed and complement must be open.
2. If a set A has an isolated point, it cannot be an open set.  => I think it is true, but can not think of proof.

3.Set A is closed if and only if A= closure of A => True by following definition.

4. If A is a bounded set, then s=supA is a limit point of A => False Let A={1,2,3} then supA is 3 but 3 is not a limit point.
5. Every finite set is closed => true, singleton element is closed and finite union of closed sets is closed.
6. An open set that contains every rational number must necessarily be all of R
   I think it is true, but anyone can explain?

If there are any wrong answers, please point out and show me some counterexmaples.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Looks good.
2. This is true in $\mathbb{R}$, but not in general metric spaces. For a trivial example, consider the discrete metric on a single point; for a slightly less trivial example, consider the set $\{1\}\subset\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$ with the metric induced from $\mathbb{R}$.
3. Looks good.
4. Looks good.
5. True in metric spaces but not in topological spaces, for instance by taking the indiscrete topology.
6. False, consider $(-\infty,\sqrt{2})\cup(\sqrt{2},\infty)$. There are stranger examples; for instance, if we enumerate $\mathbb{Q}=(q_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, then $\bigcup (q_i-2^{-i},q_i+2^{-1})$ is open and contains the rationals, but the sum of the lengths of these intervals is merely $4$!

Comment: Thank you so much! All of out questions are related to R, but I appreciate your extra comment on each question.

Comment: About 2.  The only way for a set with an isolated point to be open, would be if the isolated point is isolated in the metric.  For the set to be open, means all points in a neigherbood around x are in the set.  But to be an isolated point means there is a neighbor with no other points in the set.  These are contradictory ideas and the only way they can both be true is if there are no points whatsoever (except the point itself) in a neighbor. I.e. it's an isolated point in the metric space.  Ex. If the metric space is the integers, all sets are open.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the six question is false because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a totally disconnected subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. In particoular there isn't the Dedekind's axiom for the rational numbers. For example take the open set $\lbrace r\in \mathbb{R}:r<\sqrt{2} \rbrace\cup\lbrace r\in\mathbb{R}:r>\sqrt{2} \rbrace\supseteq \mathbb{Q} $. This is open because is union of open sets of the real line.